# Lectura de archivo CSV desde C#

Tags: c#

Alguien sabe como puedo leer una archivo CSV actual mente puedo leer todo el archivo Con File.ReadAllLines() pero el archivo que tengo que leer contiene un renglón de encabezado lo quiero es ignorar ese renglón y empezar a leer después de el en este caso ese renglón se almacena en el arreglo 0 y los datos que necesarios leer son en el arreglo 1 esto es lo que tengo:

```
string[] lineas1 = File.ReadAllLines(Ruta);
```

espero puedan apoyarme saludos.c

Comment: Te recomiendo usar alguna librería de ayuda para gestionar archivos csv, como por ejemplo https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edito**: Como indica @gbianchi en los comentarios, utilizar `ReadAllLines` y `Linq` en este caso no es lo mejor ya que estamos usando la memoria de forma ineficiente.

Lo mejor es que utilices `StreamReader` para leer la primera línea (con `sr.ReadLine();`) y a continuación el resto. Además esto te permite un tratamiento adicional de las líneas (si deseas hacerlo) y añadir los elementos a una lista en vez de trabajar con `arrays`:

```
List<string> lineas = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path))
{
    sr.ReadLine();
    while (sr.Peek() != -1)
    {
       lineas.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Te dejo también la alternativa con `ReadAllLines` y `Linq`. Podrías utilizar el método [Skip](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2) de [Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) para saltar la primera fila

```
using System.Linq;
string[] lineas1 = File.ReadAllLines(Ruta);
lineas1 = lineas1.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Y porque no directamente leer desde la linea 1 ;) si igual tiene que recorrerlas todas..aca lo unico que haces es volver a copiar todo el array a otra posicion de memoria...

Comment: Sí, esa era otra opción :). He puesto esta solución porque el OP está utilizando ReadAllLines aunque seguramente fuera más eficiente usar StreamReader leyendo la primera línea y tratando el resto.

Comment: si pero si ya hace mal usando readall, pero si despues pasa todo ese bodoque a otro bodoque, solo para evitar la linea 1, que seguro, mas que seguro, la va a evitar cuando recorra todo en un for ;)

Comment: Cierto se me fue el nombre es CSV gracias por el dato ya puede realizar una prueba y funciona de manera correcta saludos Men